# Iterate using all elements of multiple lists

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I need to iterate through multiple lists to build a new list of urls in Python 3.8

I have those lists:

```
days = ['01', '02']
months = ['Jan', 'Feb']
years = ['1990', '1991']
urls = []
```

I expect the output to be:

```
urls = ['someurl/01_Jan_1990', 'someurl/02_Jan_1990', 'someurl/01_Feb_1990', 'someurl/02_Feb_1990',
'someurl/01_Jan_1991', 'someurl/02_Jan_1991', 'someurl/01_Feb_1991', 'someurl/02_Feb_1991']
```

I tried unsuccessfully to use `zip`:

```
days = ['01', '02']
months = ['Jan', 'Feb']
years = ['1990', '1991']
urls = []

for day, month, year in zip(days, months, years):
    url = f'someurl/{day}_{month}_{year}'
    urls.append(url)

print(urls)
```

Output:

```
['someurl/01_Jan_1990', 'someurl/02_Feb_1991']
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in a list-comprehension::

```
from itertools import product


days = ['01', '02']
months = ['Jan', 'Feb']
years = ['1990', '1991']

urls = [f"someurl/{u[0]}_{u[1]}_{u[2]}" for u in product(days, months, years)]
```

alternatively the f-string `f"someurl/{'_'.join(u)}"` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for day in days:
    for month in months:
        for year in year:
            url = f'someurl/{day}_{month}_{year}'
            urls.append(url)
```